# Add Element to Initialized Array List

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a question regarding the use of a List after it has bee created.  I am getting an java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException in the following snippet.  Any ideas?

```
List <Integer> aList = Arrays.asList(3, 4);
if (condition)
    aList.add(5);
```

This doesn't work either

```
aList.add(new Integer(5));
```

I want to initialize a list with common values then add conditional ones.

Answer (score 2):

From [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29):

> Returns a **fixed-size** list backed by the specified array. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.)

(emphasis mine)

If you want a List that can resize, use

```
new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays.asList returns a fixed-size array, you can't add to it. See [api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29).

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29),

> **Returns a *fixed-size list* backed by the specified array**. (Changes to the returned list "write through" to the array.) This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination with Collection.toArray(). The returned list is serializable and implements RandomAccess.

The list returned does not support addition of new element.

Answer (score 0):

- As per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29): the `asList(T...)` function returns a fixed size list backed by the specified array.
- the returned list doesn't have a `add(E element)` function implementation referring to the source.

You will need to do:

```
    ArrayList<Integer>aList  =  new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3, 4));
```